# How to use getquery with amplify <Connect/> component in React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have been trying to use the  together with a getquery in react but I can't get it to work. Below is the code I put together

```
const input = {
        id: this.props.Id
      };

        return (
                  <div>
                    <Connect
                            query={graphqlOperation(getRecords, input)}
                            subscription={graphqlOperation(onCreateRecords)}
                            onSubscriptionMsg={onNewRecord}
                          >
                            {({data, loading, error}) => {
                                    if (loading) return "Loading"
                                    if (error) return "Error"
                                    const ListRecord = data.getRecords
                                    console.log('ListRecord', ListRecord)                  
                                    //console.log returns undefined
                                    return <div>...
                                      </div>  
                            }}
                      </Connect>
                    </div>
```

Deos anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say based on what you've posted alone.  Is there any additional information in the 'data' object?

Also, Have you tried doing:

```
query={graphqlOperation(getRecords,  {input})}
```

Comment: nope still returns undefined. what would you need in order to help me cuz thats pretty much the entire class thanks